# Android Drone get video from controller APM 2.8

Tags: android, video, joystick, drone.io

I'm searching for information on how to program an android app that could read a video from a controller APM installed on the joystick of a drone.

The joystick already receives videos from the drone and saves them on his hard disk.
So now I want to understand how it communicates with the joystick.

I saw Tower (DroidPlanner 3) and AndroPilot projects but I didn't understand if they can help me to communicate with the joystick and get the videos.
Thanks in advance :)